# lftp sftp file to specific directory

Tags: scripting, sftp

I need to copy a file over SFTP to a specific directory. I use LFTP because this connection requires an IP6 mDNS name.

```
lftp sftp://admin:password123@serial.local -e "put file.txt; bye"
```

This works, but the file ends up in /home/admin

I want the file to end up in /home/admin/upload

Can I somehow specify the destination directory? I'd be happy to use an additional command to do so, but it must be scripted with lftp/sftp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps all you need is an additional command:

```
lftp sftp://admin:password123@serial.local -e "cd upload; put file.txt; bye"
```

Comment: That works. You know I've been having a long day when I can't figure that out on my own. Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad it worked; I'm not an lftp user, but saw that `-e` appeared to take multiple commands.

Comment: Good find. LFTP is pretty cool. It's one of the only CLI utilities in OSX that can resolve an IPv6 mdns name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-O` flag to specify the target directory.

`lftp sftp://admin:password123@serial.local -e "put -O remote/directory file.txt; bye"`

Find the docs here: https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html